# Some PyQt5 Checkboxes are unclickable after being moved

Tags: user-interface, checkbox, pyqt, pyqt5, widget

I'm creating a to-do list where a checkbox, textbox (QLineEdit), and QComboBox (to set Priority 1, 2, etc.) are added each time the "Add Task" button is clicked. When the checkbox for each corresponding task is clicked, the task would move to the bottom of the list of tasks. Conversely, if a priority is set, then the task is moved to the top of the list of tasks.

The problem is that in certain circumstances, when I click on the checkbox, nothing happens. The signal that identifies that the checkbox state has changed is never sent. It's almost like the checkbox isn't there, even though it (or at least, the image of it) is. This problem happens if *none* of the priorities are set with unchecking—checking any given task works, but certain tasks cannot be unchecked. Other tasks are able to be unchecked, and sometimes if I go back to the task that couldn't be unchecked after unchecking something else, it'll be checkable again. If I were to set some tasks to have a priority and then go and try to check the checkboxes, some checkboxes won't be able to be checked at all. Again, if I were to check some other task and then go back to the task that wasn't able to be checked, it might be able to be checked this time around.

I think the error might be coming from moving the checkboxes... for some reason the functionality behind some of the checkboxes is lost going through the code. One notable thing is tabbing through the items in the GUI. Once items are moved, hitting tab will go through the items in the same order that it was originally set up in (so the cursor will essentially jump around the textboxes instead of going in order from top to bottom). Not sure if that has anything to do with the error; it's just something I've noticed. I'm don't know if this is an error within PyQt5 itself, or if it's a fixable error within the code.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QComboBox,
    QPushButton, QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QTextEdit, QMainWindow, QAction, QShortcut, QCheckBox)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QKeySequence)
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QObject

class App(QMainWindow): 
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.i = 40
        self.j = 80
        self.counter = 1
        self.list_eTasks = []
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #sets up window
        self.setWindowTitle('To-Do List')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 855)

        #button
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Add Task", self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.add_task_button_clicked)
        
        #close the window via keyboard shortcuts
        self.exit = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+W" or "Ctrl+Q"), self)
        self.exit.activated.connect(self.close)

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def add_task_button_clicked(self):
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText(str(self.counter))
        self.label.move(5, self.i)

        self.btn1.move(50, self.j)

        self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox.resize(280, 40)

        self.checkbox = QCheckBox(self)
        self.checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self.click_box)
    
        self.combobox = QComboBox(self)
        self.combobox.addItem("No Priority")
        self.combobox.addItem("Priority 1")
        self.combobox.addItem("Priority 2")
        
        self.combobox.addItem("Priority 3")
        self.combobox.activated[str].connect(self.combobox_changed)
        
        self.obj = eTask(self.checkbox, self.textbox, self.combobox)
        self.list_eTasks.append(self.obj)


        self.textbox.show()
        self.label.show()
        self.checkbox.show()
        self.combobox.show()

        self.i += 40
        self.j += 40
        self.counter += 1
        self.sort_eTasks()

    def click_box(self, state):
        self.sort_eTasks()

    def move_everything(self, new_list):
        count = 0
        for item in new_list:
            y_value = ((40)*(count + 1))
            item.check.move(20, y_value)
            item.text.move(50, y_value)
            item.combo.move(350, y_value)
            count += 1
        return

    def combobox_changed(self, state):
        #make new list to not include any already checked off items
        for task in self.list_eTasks:
            if task.combo.currentText() == "Priority 1":
                task.priority = 1
            elif task.combo.currentText() == "Priority 2":
                task.priority = 2
            elif task.combo.currentText() == "Priority 3":
                task.priority = 3
            else:
                task.priority = 10
        self.sort_eTasks()

    def sort_eTasks(self):
        self.list_eTasks.sort(key=lambda eTask: eTask.getRank())
        self.move_everything(self.list_eTasks)
        for task in self.list_eTasks:
            print(str(task.priority) + " pos: " + str(task.check.pos()))

        print("-----------------------------------")

class eTask: 
    check = ""
    text = ""
    combo = ""
    priority = 10

    def __init__(self, c, t, co):
        self.check = c
        self.text = t
        self.combo = co
    
    def setP(self, p):
        self.priority = p

    def getRank(self):
        if self.check.isChecked():
            return self.priority + 100
        else:
            return self.priority

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your code is somehow confused and a bit too extensive. Can you please at least check the indentation? You can learn more about it by reading about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) (also, check the preview of your question, to ensure that's correct).

Comment: @musicamante Fixed! Thank you for letting me know; the format got messed up when I copy/pasted in the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems with your code, I'll try to address all of them.

1. The sorting mechanism is not good: it only happens when an item changes the priority (while it should also apply whenever the user clicks the checkbox)
2. Using low values like those results in unexpected behavior: if I have a `priority 1` checked its priority is augmented by 10, so why should it go under a `priority 2` or even 3?
3. The sorting mechanism should be centralized, instead of being split into more functions that don't do anything else: *"one function to rule them all"* ;-) Don't check for the combobox contents and then sort basing on another external function call: just call a single function that checks for the combobox *and* the checkbox, *then* sort the contents; remember: while OOP is about modularity, you should avoid unnecessary fragmentation (remember the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle));
4. You should probably not connect to the `activated` signal, and you should certainly not use the `[str]` overload (checking for a string is rarely a good idea for index based widgets); use [`currentIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop) and its [`currentIndexChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) signal instead;
5. Using fixed geometries for child widgets is something that should be avoided as much as possible; layout managers exist for **lots** of *very good reasons* (for example, I couldn't click on the QLineEdit if the mouse cursor was too close to the check box, even if it's *over* the line edit); note that you should avoid using `setGeometry` for the top level window also;
6. You should never set instance attributes that are going to be overwritten by a *different* object: you're continuously overwriting them (`self.label`, `self.textbox`, etc.), and the result is that making them instance attributes is completely useless; since you're already creating them with a parent widget, the garbage collector won't delete them at the end of the function, so you should only use local variables instead (`label = QLabel()`, etc...);
7. Using a class like you did is not very useful: you're going to group all those widgets anyway, so it's better to use a *container* widget which not only will manage its children (see the point above about layouts), but will "centralize" all necessary programming logic;
8. Avoid similar names for class and variables if they refer to different object types: in your case, `app` refers to the `QApplication` instance, but `App` is a `QMainWidget` subclass;

Here's a possible reimplementation of your code:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class TaskWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    priorityChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    lastChanged = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
    def __init__(self, title='', parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.textBox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(title)
        layout.addWidget(self.textBox)
        self.textBox.setMinimumWidth(240)
        self.priorityCombo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.priorityCombo)
        self.priorityCombo.addItems([
            'No priority', 
            'Priority 1', 
            'Priority 2', 
            'Priority 3', 
        ])
        self.priorityCombo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updatePriority)
        self.checkBox.toggled.connect(self.updatePriority)

    def updatePriority(self):
        # update the "lastChanged" variable, ensuring that the sorting puts on 
        # top the last changed task
        self.lastChanged = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        self.priorityChanged.emit()

    def priority(self):
        priority = self.priorityCombo.currentIndex()
        # set an arbitrary (but still reasonable) priority that would be fine for 
        # more items in the same priority
        if priority > 0:
            priority *= 100
        else:
            priority = self.priorityCombo.count() * 100
        if self.checkBox.isChecked():
            priority -= 1
        return priority, self.lastChanged.msecsTo(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())


class TaskApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central)
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        self.taskLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        layout.addLayout(self.taskLayout)

        self.addTaskButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add task')
        layout.addWidget(self.addTaskButton)
        self.addTaskButton.clicked.connect(self.addTask)

        self.tasks = []
        self.addTask()

    def addTask(self):
        task = TaskWidget('Task no. {}'.format(len(self.tasks) + 1))
        if not self.taskLayout.count():
            # this is for the first item only; we cannot use rowCount, since it 
            # always returns at least 1, even if it's empty
            row = 0
        else:
            row = self.taskLayout.rowCount()
        self.taskLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(str(row + 1)))
        self.taskLayout.addWidget(task, row, 1)
        self.tasks.append(task)
        task.priorityChanged.connect(self.sortTasks)

    def sortTasks(self):
        tasks = self.tasks[:]
        self.tasks.clear()
        # since we're using a QGridLayout, we don't need to relate to 
        # insertWidget(), which is index based and might result in some 
        # inconsistencies while "regenerating" the UI; in this case, the 
        # grid will be the same, we're only going to rearrange the child widgets
        for row, taskWidget in enumerate(sorted(tasks, key=lambda w: w.priority())):
            self.taskLayout.addWidget(taskWidget, row, 1)
            self.tasks.append(taskWidget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TaskApp()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I just guessed the priority implementation, but that's not the point.
I also added a datetime check, so that the last changed item with the same priority will always be on top.