# Why are checkboxes unclickable after moving them in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I'm trying to create an array of checkboxes dynamically in my window so I can select different sections of data in my program. The checkboxes are created in the right positions, but when it comes to clicking them, they don't respond to any inputs.

Here is the code responsible for creating the checkboxes:

```
  def initialize_checkbox_array(self, xdimension, ydimension, xoffset, yoffset):
    for i in (range(ydimension)):
      for j in reversed(range(xdimension)):
        btn = checked(self, i, j)
        btn.move(int(xoffset - (xdimension * 17 /2))+17*j, yoffset+17*i) # xoffset calculation to make sure that the grid is centered
```

Here, xdimension and ydimension are the number of checkboxes I want in the grid, and xoffset and yoffset are just to position it in the window correctly. The `reversed()` in the third line is just for the data that it's taking in, which isn't relevant to this question right now.

Here's the class `checked()` that I use to create the checkboxes:

```
class checked(QCheckBox):
  def __init__(self, parent, x, y):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

I've think I've narrowed it down to a problem with mouse input, since when I add a line to `checked()` `self.setChecked(True)`, the checkmarks appear with a check in them, but they still aren't interactable. Also, if I add a checkbox through Qt Creator, that particular checkbox works as expected.

I've looked for a solution and came across [this question 2 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408195/some-pyqt5-checkboxes-are-unclickable-after-being-moved), but to my understanding this is an issue with other logic in his code and not so much the checkbox itself not responding to inputs.

Edit: after some more fiddling, the checkboxes in the first column are clickable, but not the rest. I'm even more confused.

Comment: Why don't you use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)?

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that these existed. Thanks for the heads up! I probably won't use it this time because I already have a solution, but it's useful for next time.

Comment: Well, sorry to disappoint you, but that's not a good solution: it's an unreliable workaround. Qt uses complex systems to properly draw widgets and allow user interaction, and that system is based on many aspects, including platform defaults and system settings. For instance, if High DPI screens or font scaling are used. Long story short, while your code *may* seem to work fine on your computer, it will probably create **a lot** of issues on somebody else. Qt developers put extreme efforts in providing code that is usable in almost any of those conditions, in order to always make UI *usable*.

Comment: 99.9% of the times, using fixed geometries is a wrong choice. The remaining 0.1% is a careful choice made with extreme awareness; a conscious one, considering the above aspects (and many more), with the developer being aware that avoiding layouts might result in unexpected behavior (aka: making the program unusable). And, sorry to be blunt, but your admission in not knowing about layout managers puts you in another category: the 100% of the times a beginner Qt developer tries to reinvent the wheel not knowing the plethora of things layout management involves. You want a grid? Use QGridLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into it a little more, it turns out that each checkbox has a bounding box for the text to the right of it (I assume reversed for right to left languages like arabic), and because of my reversed function, it draws the checkboxes from right to left, meaning that the bounding box for the column to the left of it gets in front of the hitbox of the checkbox. The solution is to a. space them out a lot so this doesn't happen, or b. make sure that the boxes are drawn from left to right.

It's especially strange, because even when I pass an empty or one character string to `QCheckBox` via `self.setText('')`, the size of the bounding box is the same. No idea if this is an intended feature or not, but the solution for now is to work around it.

My current work around:

```
class checked(QCheckBox):
  def __init__(self, parent, x, y):
    super(checked, self).__init__(parent)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.setText('')
    self.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
```